# Static code analysis for a Rails application during a Jenkins build job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jenkins, static-analysis

2.0 application which should be checked up.

I've tried it with sonarqube, But sonerqube only can check the HTML parts of the application. But I want to do static code analysis for the controllers and models as well.

I've found rcov and lots of others but the don't work ...

The analysis should be trigered from the jenkins server during a normal build job. Are there any possible solutions similar to sonarqube? It would be great if I don't have to change something in my Gemfile.

Thanks for your help.

Shell Build task:

```
rubocop -R --format html -o log/rubocop.html
```

Jenkins Error

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1902542517750944782.sh
+ rubocop -R --format html -o log/rubocop.html
/tmp/hudson1902542517750944782.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson1902542517750944782.sh: rubocop: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: have you tried `Rubocop`? https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to set it up in Jenkins and getting it working. Where do I have to install the gem? in jenkins or where?

Comment: gem is installed in rails app. Personally have not used it with Jenkins but It is possible to run it as shell script. Here some Jenkins tips are explained https://github.com/eitoball/rubocop-checkstyle_formatter

Comment: I've tried it ... I've added the gem in Gemfile of the application. Wenn I push to bitbucket the jenkins starts with build... 

I've added a shell Buildtask in Jenkins, but I got an error. Added above

Comment: looks like `rubocop`is executed outside of rails app location. Do you able to run this in terminal?

Comment: terminal of jenkins?

Comment: no, from bash in the rails app location

Comment: yeah but in the workspace on jenkins server?

Comment: try both, this could be the matter

Comment: hmm okay gonna try but what I want is that the jenkins runs the analysis not locally on my dev pc. Jenkis should start the analysis an publish it like its done with sonar qube

Comment: Yeah I get. I think you should install rubocop on Jenkins server `gem install rubocop`

Comment: goona try it just a second :) ... but I don't have root rights on jenkins. its a docker conatiner

Comment: gem isn't installed on jenkins ...

Comment: then you can remove it from Gemfile ad install as standalone gem on Jenkins server

Comment: yeah first I have to install gem on jenkins or?